# Adding material-ui/core/Table causes a data exception even though it's not even linked yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-saga

**What I started with**

I have a Redux Saga generator function that loads my (mock) API data:

```
function* fetchPickingScans({orderReference}){
    try{
        const response = yield call( scanningMockApi.getPickingScans, orderReference);

        if (response !== undefined && response.scannedItems !== undefined){
            const scans = response.scannedItems;
            yield put(loadPickingScansSuccess(scans));
        }
    }
    catch (error){
        console.warn(error);
    }
}
```

This data is passed to a dumb component:

```
<div>
    <ScansOverview scans={pickingScans}/>
</div>
```

As I'm setting things up, I kept displaying the data simple, just an unstructured set-up:

```
const ScansOverview = ({scans, classes}) => {
    var scansArray = Object.values(scans); // ToArray
    if (scansArray[0] === undefined){
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>Please wait.</div>
        )
    }else{
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                {
                    scansArray.map(scanItem => {
                        return (
                            <div key={scanItem.id}>
                                <ScanLine scan={scanItem}/>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This works fine technically until I try to add a `material-ui/core/Table` structure.

**Update per request**

The actual page code that sets everything up:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ScansOverview from './scansOverview';
import { loadPickingScans } from '../../actions';
import { pickingScansForOrderReference } from '../../selectors';

class OrderPickingScansPage extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        const { loadPickingScans } = this.props;
        loadPickingScans(this.props.match.params.orderReference);
    }

    render() {
        const {pickingScans} = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <ScansOverview scans={pickingScans}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const getPickingScansForOrderReference = pickingScansForOrderReference();
    return {
      pickingScans: getPickingScansForOrderReference(state)
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        loadPickingScans: () => dispatch(loadPickingScans())
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrderPickingScansPage);
```

**What I'm going for**

As mentioned, the above displays the data, proving that the set up works, but in a way that is not yet functionally desirable. I need to add structure to the page.

So I added `material-ui/core` for it's table functionality:

```
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
```

For some reason, actually even adding an empty table structure causes a data exception:

```
const ScansOverview = ({scans, classes}) => {
    var scansArray = Object.values(scans); // ToArray
    if (scansArray[0] === undefined){
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>Please wait.</div>
        )
    }else{
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <Table>
                    <TableBody>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Test</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Causes:

[image]

> As I said, I'm not even linking the data to the table yet, so why
>   would this happen?

PS: ESLint does not throw any compile errors.

Comment: could you add the code that you are using for assigning to the `pickingScans` variable? It looks like that's missing and I suspect that's causing an issue since it looks to be asynchronous?

Comment: @RudolfOlah I've added the page code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing a general package update and clean based on `npm outdated`, made sure I was using `@material-ui/core` only (not material-ui) and everything worked.

[npm outdated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would isolate the `fetchPickingScans` and perhaps replace it with a function that always returns the same list and doesn't even try to fetch the data from anywhere else.

You will have to debug this piece by piece but I think the error message contains the clue that `fetchPickingScans` is causing the issue. The async star/yield look like they could be the problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: I fixed it by doing a general package update and clean based on npm outdated, made sure I was using @material-ui/core only (not material-ui) and everything worked! While not the solution, your suggestion lead me to it because I found that out through isolating the components that make out the application until I found what the issue was. So thanks for taking the time to get back to my question!

Comment: ah the usual "delete `node_modules` and reinstall and update and hope for the best" technique, I've used it many times with npm/node packages ;) glad it worked!

Comment: Pretty much :).